# Cannot map nested field with @Mapper

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct, mapper

I'm trying to create a mapper using lombok `@Mapper` and I get the following error:

```
Property "delivery" has no write accessor in ClassA for target name "classBB_variable.delivery"
```

The code:

```
@Mapper
    @Mapping(target = "classBB_variable.customerId", source = "classA_variable.customerId")
    @Mapping(target = "classBB_variable.delivery", source = "classA_variable.classAA_variable.delivery")
    ClassB toCreateRequest(ClassA classA_variable);



@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassA {    
    private UUID customerId;
    private ClassAA classAA_variable;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class ClassAA {    
    private String delivery;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class ClassB {
    private ClassBB classBB_variable;

}

@Data
@Builder
public class ClassBB {
    private UUID customerId;
    private String delivery;
}
```

As the map for `customerId` works fine, I'm assuming the issue is the additional level introduced with `classA_variable.classAA_variable.delivery`.

Has anyone already dealt with this situation? How can I solve it?

Comment: Create a setter for property `delivery`.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the final modifiers and now the error changed to "No read accessor found for property "classBB_variable" in target type". However the @Data annotation should have created the getter for the property

Comment: Both MapStruct and Lombok are Annotation Processors being active at build time.  There is a section on MapStruct‘s website how to use both in parallel:  https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok

Comment: I'm already using lombok-mapstruct-binding and the versions also coincide. The example is a bit trivial unfortunately

Comment: This seems to be a know issue with MapStruct, documented at [github](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2348). Unfortunately, none of the solutions mentioned at the end do actually work.